# WebAPI OData include related entities without using $expand option

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, odata

Expanding upon [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071839/include-related-entities-with-webapi-odata-request)

From the documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value), it states:

"When you query an OData entity or collection, the default response does not include related entities."

Is there any way to include related entities **without** using the $expand option?

Comment: you can do it as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907701/odata-expand-query-result-by-default/48061879#48061879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to contain the related entities without using the $expand. But if you only want the related ones, you can use navigation property such as:
~/Categories(1)/Products

Comment: this is not correct. see my comment on the question