# Odata expand query result by default

Tags: c#, .net, odata

Is there a way to auto expand nested entity in the response with odata 5.7?

Because by default we have to add ?$expand=myNestedEntity

Comment: Hi @Jag.  If my answer below has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 7):

In your entity class definition, use the [AutoExpand](https://learn.microsoft.com/odata/webapi/autoexpand-attribute) attribute on the navigation properties you would like to have expanded.

Namespace: [Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.builder.autoexpandattribute)

> Represents an Attribute that can be placed *on a navigation property* to
>   specify it is auto expanded, or placed *on a class* to specify all
>   navigation properties are auto expanded.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, this can be accomplished with `fluent api`.

```
builder.EntitySet<MyType>("MyType").EntityType.Expand(SelectExpandType.Automatic, "ExpandedField1", "ExpandedField2");
```